# как вывести жанры (types) аниме

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

как вывести жанры (types) аниме, либо выводит весь текст, либо если ты добавил get_text(), пишет ошибку

Ошибка в 20 строке
types": item.find("span", class_ = "anime-genre d-none d-sm-inline") – 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
def safe():
    with open("parse_info.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(f'{comp["title"]} -> {comp["genres"]} -> {comp["type"]} -> {comp["types"]}\n')
def parse():
    URL = "https://animego.org/anime/filter/year-from-2023/apply"
    r = requests.get(URL) 
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    items = html.findAll("div", class_ = "media-body")
    comps = []
    links = html.findAll('a')
    for link in links:
        linkdetail = link.get('href')
    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            "title": item.find("div", class_ = "h5 font-weight-normal mb-1").get_text(strip=True),
            "genres": item.find("span", class_ = "mb-2").get_text(strip=True),
            "type": item.find("a", class_ = "text-link-gray text-underline").get_text(strip=True),
            "types": item.find("span", class_ = "anime-genre d-none d-sm-inline")

        })
    global comp
    for comp in comps:
        print(f'{comp["title"]} -> {comp["genres"]} -> {comp["type"]} -> {comp["types"]}')
        safe()
parse()
```

Comment: "types": item.find("span", class_ = "anime-genre d-none d-sm-inline")

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Окей, идем далее ) Текст ошибки вам понятен? Вы уверены, что `item.find()` нашел такой объект и у него есть атрибут `get_text`?

Comment: Если честно, не особо понятен

Comment: это означает, что ничего не нашлось, а у ничего нет текста.

Answer (score 0):

Как Вам верно заметили в комментариях, не у всех Аниме присутствует описание, поэтому не на каждой странице есть `class_ = "anime-genre d-none d-sm-inline"` Вы можете обработать эту ошибку в блоке `try, except` следующим образом.

```
...
    for item in items:
        try:
            types = item.find("span", class_ = "anime-genre d-none d-sm-inline").get_text(strip=True)
        except AttributeError:
            types = 'No types'
            
        comps.append({
            "title": item.find("div", class_ = "h5 font-weight-normal mb-1").get_text(strip=True),
            "genres": item.find("span", class_ = "mb-2").get_text(strip=True),
            "type": item.find("a", class_ = "text-link-gray text-underline").get_text(strip=True),
            "types": types,
        })
...
```

Теперь если у аниме есть описание, то текст будет сохраняться, а если нет то будет сохраняться `No types`(можете изменить по Вашему вкусу)